# How to use Maven WAR overlay to extend a WAR with another project?

Tags: java, maven, war

I'm trying to include a WAR in a project, to extend it, similar to the question [How to extend/customize a WAR with another project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4088019/1076143). As far as I can tell, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4088112/) (use Maven WAR overlays) seems to be the right one for my project. However, I can't figure out how I can get this to work.

I included the Maven WAR plugin in my pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</plugin>
```

and added the WAR as a dependency (local repository):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>nl.surfnet.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>apis-authorization-server-war</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

When I now compile and deploy the application, everything works just fine, the parent project is deployed as is. I just had to include a .properties file, which isn't included in the WAR, in which you can plug in your own classes which override the default behaviour of the project.

Now I want to extend a class, to add some custom behaviour, but I can't figure out how to do this. My problem is, that I can't even include the class I want to extend. As far as I understand, WARs are not thought to be included in another project, as they are intended to be published to a container server. But isn't the WAR Overlay plugin thought to give you exactly that funcitonality?

Then I found the [Warpath plugin](http://static.appfuse.org/maven-warpath-plugin/) which sounds like it does exactly what I want: "Develop with classes included in the war artifact /WEB-INF/classes directory by including them in the project classpath."

Adding the plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.appfuse</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-warpath-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-classes</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and a second dependency (type warpath), as described in the plugin documentation:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>nl.surfnet.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>apis-authorization-server-war</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>warpath</type>
</dependency>
```

However again, including the class doesn't seem to work. Netbeans tells me that the package I try to import does not exist.

Strangely though, I can now deploy my project, which works fine, as long as I don't try to use my new class, even if I introduce syntax errors in that class. The class doesn't even seem to be compiled anymore.

To be sure that the problem isn't due to the project I'm trying to extend, I wrote two new minimal test projects, where one extends the other. Again I got the same behavior. I didn't include those projects here, as the code is the same as the one provided above, with just another `groupId` and `artifactId`.

Comment: Have you read http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html ? Apart from that why are you using an old version of maven-war-plugin ?

Comment: There is no "war overlay plugin" - there is only a war plugin which has an overlay feature that you can configure - and you didn't configure it. The answer you link to links itself to documentation on the war plugin that demonstrates how to do it. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html

Comment: @khmarbaise I updated the version, in the pom.xml file generated by Netbeans, the old version was used.

Comment: @Gimby The documentation says "In previous versions of the WAR Plugin, no configuration was necessary. This is still the case if you are happy with the default settings. However, if you need more control, read on!" I'll still try to configure it manually and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I added a configuration section, in which I included two overlays: the other war as well as en empty overlay (which means "this project"). The result is exactly the same.